# How to reduce builder time in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working with eclipse  . When Eclipse  restart / open , I am unable to work until the builder , building workspace or finished . How can I reduce this timing ?

Please look at the screenshot .

[image]

Sometimes my eclipse is hanged due to that . I am unable to continue my work process . It happened not only on restart . For eclipse project open / close . Any solution regarding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way is to suspend all the validation when ever you create a new work space in eclipse, this will reduce some of time at eclipse start up

For this go to `window --> preferences` there  search for `validation` and check `suspend all validators`    See image for more detail
[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I suspend all validators besides javascript , java .

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this kind of issue. I won't say this is the complete solution for the problem. But what I did is:

Look for the plug-ins installed in your eclispe & not being used in your project. Uninstall them from eclipse.

Also look at your code. There might be some code that tries to refer to some kind of scripts or plug-ins that might be skipped/removed.

This will reduce some time of building workspace.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse workspace builder is triggered *only* on resource changes. So if it starts to build immediately after launching Eclipse, something changed the workspace content. This might be

- another plugin in the same Eclipse instance or
- a tool outside Eclipse, which modified the workspace files during the time that Eclipse was not running.

In your case this might be related to Mercurial, judging by the "hg cache" string in the message. So check whether or not you have some automatic updates of version controlled files.

Comment: My projects in eclipse are using hg mercurial plugin . But I didn't understand "**automatic updates of version controlled files**".

Comment: For instance, do you have some other external tool, which automatically updates your Mercurial repository every 20 minutes to merge changes from a remote repository? That would then be a modification of the files in your Eclipse workspace and Eclipse would react by re-building on the next start.