# Eclipse (Juno) hangs on startup

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

History:

- I have ADT v21 installed, and it is built on Eclipse Juno
- Installed plugins SVNKIt 1.3.8, Subversive SVN connectors, Sequoyah, Easy Shell 1.4

Eclipse mostly hangs on restart, and some times even on fresh start up. It's only working if 
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench is deleted, I am unable to find the root cause why workbench is reason for eclipse hang.

Can any one give suggest one time solution for this?

Comment: [Check if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928370/how-to-reduce-builder-time-in-eclipse/12928535#12928535)

Comment: @sfah: thank you but I am not looking to reduce the start up time, in fact in my case eclipse hangs.